# Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with MyDates as 
(

    SELECT
        cast( '01-oct-2020' as date ) AS MyDate,
        DATENAME( DW, cast('01-oct-2020' as date ) ) AS NameOfDay

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        DATEADD( DAY, 1, MyDate ) AS MyDate,
        DATENAME( DW, DATEADD( DAY, 1, MyDate ) ) AS NameOfDay
    FROM
        MyDates
    WHERE
        DATEADD( DAY, 1, MyDate ) < DATEADD( DAY, -1, DATEADD( MONTH, 3, MyDate ) )
)
select
    *
from
    MyDates
order by
    MyDate desc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I am trying above code. It runs fine if I run it without `order by` clause.

SQL throws an error on using `order by` clause.

> Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow

Please help

Comment: It won't fix the issue, but you should move your `NameOfDay` column to your outer `SELECT`. It isn't needed inside the CTE.

Comment: I _think_ the overflow is because `ORDER BY` causes an eager-evaluation of your query **before** the `maxrecursion` option is applied, so the CTE is computed recursively to infinity but actually fails when it passes `9999-DEC-31`. Anyway, **there are better ways to generate ranges of dates than a CTE**.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using non-standard date functions). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: there are better ways to generate ranges of dates than a CTE. eager to know I am a neweb here sir

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server code so I added the tag.  Please tag your questions with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your problem has nothing to do with the `ORDER BY`.  The problem is the recursive CTE.

This condition always evaluates to true:

```
   DATEADD( DAY, 1, MyDate ) < DATEADD( DAY, -1, DATEADD( MONTH, 3, MyDate ) )
```

so the recursion never ends.  Why?  `MyDate` is always less than the date 3 months and 1 day in the future.  This only refers to columns within a single row.  So, it is not what you intend.

I suppose you want something like this:

```
with MyDates as (
    SELECT CAST( '2020-10-01' as date ) AS MyDate,
           DATENAME(weekday, '2020-10-01') AS NameOfDay,
           CAST( '2020-10-01' as date )  as orig_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, MyDate ) AS MyDate,
           DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD( DAY, 1, MyDate ) ) AS NameOfDay,
           orig_date
    FROM MyDates
    WHERE MyDate < DATEADD( MONTH, 3, orig_date )
)
select *
from  MyDates
order by  MyDate desc
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0619348f8a0bafc94e3de9a1f7f4d3ea) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks Gorden , Can I ask how do I identify second and fourth Saturday in this given period?

Comment: @user2922376 . . . This answers the question you have here.  If you have another question, please ask a *new* question.